# OneToOne in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, annotations, doctrine, one-to-one

I try to save related entities User and Profile. I use the cascade={"persist"} option. Data saves properly in Database except user_id field in Profile table, its equal to null. When i turn relations profile_id field in User table saves properly. Where is my mistake? Here is my relations:

User entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Profile", mappedBy="user", ,cascade={"persist"})
 */
```

Profile entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="profile", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
```

Getters & setters:

User:

```
` /**
 * @param Profile $profile
 */
public function setProfile(Profile $profile)
{
    $this->profile = $profile;
}

/**
 * @return Profile
 */
public function getProfile()
{
    return $this->profile;
}`
```

Profile:

```
`/**
 * @param User $user
 */
public function setUser(User $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}

/**
 * @return User
 */
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->user;
}`
```

Comment: Why do you have `profile_id` in you `user` table? According to your annotations you should have `user_id` within `profile` table and nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is essentially @skler answer but I couldn't explain myself in comments.

Try doing this in your `User.php`'s `setProfile()`:

```
public function setProfile(Profile $profile)
{
    $this->profile = $profile;
    $this->profile->setUser($this);
}
```

Comment: FyodorX, thanks for help) But now i am dont understand why it works, even without properly setters when i turn the relation?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you add only profile in user: `$user->addProfile($profile);` and you didn't the viceversa: `$profile->addUser($user);`

Comment: I am using the FOSUserBundle so I not handle data manualy. The `cascade` option do that for me. Or I don't understand something. I am newbie.

Comment: I guess he means in your `User`s `setProfile()`.

Comment: @FyodorX: yes maybe setProfile, there aren't getter and setter in question.

Comment: @Dobrichok: FosUserBundle doesn't have profile entity, you manage it by yourself, somewhere you add profile to user..